# What can I do if there are no portals near me in Ingress?

Tags: ingress

I live in a field, literally miles away from anywhere. There are some quantities of XM nearby and I have completely filled up my XM bar, but I have walked all around my village and there are no portals anywhere near here.

Does this mean that I am unable to play Ingress, since I'm not going to be able to level up?

What can I do if there are no portals near me in Ingress?

Comment: You can suggest places to become portals, I'm thinking about doing that to some closer landmarks, most of the portals are downtown.  I haven't done it yet so I can't tell you how well it works.  I think it has to be reviewed by a Ingress staff member after you submit it.  You can submit one by clicking and holding on the map and selecting one of the options there.

Comment: I'll have to try that then, we have a couple of "structures" nearby that I could suggest, I guess

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Everything that gives you AP in Ingress involves portals. So you are correct in that Ingress will be very dull without them around you. With that said, you can make some portal suggestions around your home and in a couple of months they may or may not be online without Niantic really telling you why.

XM is different from AP. XM works similar to stamina in other games. You need XM to perform actions on a portal. You have an XM bar, and you fill it up. The only downside to your XM bar depleting is that you will be unable to interact with portals until you have sufficient XM again. Portals deposit XM on a regular basis and because of this you usually will not have to worry about XM until at least level 4-5.

AP is experience. AP is gained from interacting with portals so to answer your original question, you are absolutely dead in the water until you get out and start hacking some portals downtown. Once you acquire a portal key you can recharge the portal remotely for a hot 10AP at a time which will never be worth it unless you are trying to keep a portal alive. You can see the amount of AP you have by tapping on your level at the top left and looking below the XM bar.

Below is a table for AP values for interacting with portals.

> - Placing a resonator                                  125 AP
> - Recharging a resonator 10AP
> - Destroying a resonator                            75 AP
> - Placing the first resonator on a portal          500 AP
> - Placing the eighth resonator on a portal             250 AP
> - Creating a link                                  313 AP
> - Destroying a link                                    187 AP
> - Creating a control field                            1250 AP
> - Destroying a control field                           750 AP
> - Applying a portal shield                             150 AP
> - Placing the final link on a field                   1563 AP
> - Destroying a [full] portal                           600 AP
> - Destroying a portal + (1) link                   787 AP
> - Destroying a portal + (2) links + control field 1724 AP
> - Destroying a portal + links + cf + capture + mods   3524 AP

This is the amount of AP you need to level up in total AP needed.

> - 1   - 0
> - 2   - 10,000
> - 3   - 30,000 (20,000 from L2 - L3)
> - 4   - 70,000
> - 5   - 150,000
> - 6   - 300,000
> - 7   - 600,000
> - 8   - 1,200,000

Answer (score 9):

Ok so I went for a jog to add some locations and check out the detail described by Mark Rogers in the comments on the question. To add a location, simply stand near it, tap and hold to bring up the menu, and select 'New Portal';

[image]

This will take you to your phone's camera screen and allow you to take a picture of whatever it is you're trying to make a portal out of. Once you have taken the picture, you will be prompted to name the location and set a description for the location, after which your new portal proposal will be submitted to Niantic Labs/Google, who will send you the following confirmation email;

> Thank you for submitting your Portal suggestion to Ingress. We will review this candidate to verify XM concentration and ensure it meets our [Portal submission guidelines](http://support.google.com/ingress/answer/2808254?&ref_topic=2799270). After additional processing, we will send you a follow-up message about your submission. This may take a few weeks.

Comment: From experience, 'by a few weeks' is on average over 2 months.

Comment: I hope it doesnt take that long!

Comment: @kalina A portal location I submitted on March 5th was accepted Monday of last week (May 13th), which means a turnaround time of about 2.5 months :(

Comment: Ouch that's a bit excessive...

Comment: My first couple took about 2 months, but since then I have had a turnaround time of about 4 weeks.

Comment: I don't see this menu option, only `Fire XMP` and `Navigate`.